# Apple Test Account Needed For Review of In-App Purchases?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

When submitting an app for review by the Apple reviewers, do I need to supply a test/demo account so they can test the in-app purchases? Or do they already have test accounts?

Comment: Are you talking about an account needed to use your app or do you mean an iTunes App Store account that can used to purchase the IAP product(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a test account for them to use. iTunes Connect has a section where you tell them what user credentials to use.